# jquery ajax requests increase of memory

Tags: jquery, ajax, memory, operator-overloading

I have an ajax request every 1 second that pulls a JSON from server and manipulate a div. After a while, browser shows a large memory use in task manager about 200, 300, 500 MB and its still growing. How can I replace new data with old without caching or anything that affect memory?

Answer (score 1):

Try nulling out the existing JSON file before each request, and be sure its writing to the same variable.  Is this happening inside a loop?  Move the variable outside of the loop and refer to it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `cache: false`:

```
$.ajax({
url: "test.html",
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#results").append(html);
}
});
```